# convert tag into rendered html before adding to document itextsharp asp.net

Tags: asp.net, itext

I have this tag:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="text-align:left;" width="100%" class="no-border">
  <tr class="test">
    <td style="text-align:left;">
      <div>
        <h2>title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="newpage"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="test">
    <td style="text-align:left;">
      <div>
        <h2>title</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="newpage"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to create a new page when the class new page is hit. So here is my code to find the string:

```
Dim input As String = strHtml
Dim pattern As String = "newpage"

Dim substrings() As String = Regex.Split(input, pattern)
For Each match As String In substrings
    document.Add(New Paragraph(match))
    document.NewPage()
Next
```

Now the issue with this is that it added the "match" text as it html tag rather than the rendered html. Is there a way I can render this and add it to the document as a separate page?

Comment: Is using a different free HTML-to-PDF conversion library an option? If so, I can post an answer that accomplishes this very easily.

Comment: @Arindam could you share please? I would love to check it out.

Comment: @TroyGizzi , see above comment , it is for you! OP mistakenly placed my name there.

Comment: If you can use a different (also free) library for converting HTML to a PDF, then I recommend **EVO HTML to PDF**. It supports the `page-break-before` CSS property. If you visit their [Live Demo](http://www.evopdf.com/demo/HTML_to_PDF/Page_Breaks/Insert_Page_Breaks_Before_After_Using_CSS.aspx) page for that feature, it provides an example. Or you can enter a simple HTML string like `<p>first page</p><p style="page-break-before: always;">second page</p>` for an easier example. (Click the "Convert HTML to PDF" button at the bottom; it will generate the PDF and send it as a download.)